# x86 array declaration with multiple 'DUP' - what does it do?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, allocation, dup

I'm studying **x86 assembly**, and I've come across this declaration:

```
array1 DB 5 DUP(2 DUP('*'))
```

What does this declaration do?

1. Allocates space for an array called `array1`, with size `DB * 5 * 2 = 10`, and 10 `*` elements.
2. Allocates space for an array called `ærray1`, with size `DB * 5` and 5 `**` elements. This would mean that 5 `*` elements get discarded.
3. Allocates a multi-dimensional array called `array1`, with size `[5][2]` and 5 `{'*', '*'}` elements.

So, is this declaration equivalent to

`char array1[10] = {'*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'}`

or is it equivalent to

`char array1[5] = {'*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'}`

?

Or maybe:

`char array1[5][2] = {{'*', '*'}, {'*', '*'}, {'*', '*'}, {'*', '*'}, {'*', '*'}}`

?

Comment: It almost certainly wouldn't be equivalent to any kind of `int` array, since `DB` means that each element is a byte.

Comment: @Michael: whoops, fixing the question

Comment: I'm fairly certain most assembly languages don't really have the concept of a multi-dimensional array. Also, generally, a `char array[10]` and a `char array[5][2]` are going to be laid out in memory identically - the type difference is an abstraction in the higher-level language. Quite possibly, the original syntax is meant to make sure the byte count is always even, to express the notion of  an array of pairs of bytes or something - that way you could conveniently and easily scale your program up to, say 37 pairs...

Comment: @twalberg: So in the end the allocated space is 10, correct?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: You could check this by placing a label directly after the declaration of `array1` and then compute the difference between that label and `array1` (either in your code or by looking at the map file).

Comment: The example is a nested dup, but not a great example, You could have something like array1 db 5 dup (1 dup '1', 2 dup '2', 3 dup '3', 4 dup '4'), which would create 50 bytes of data.

Comment: Could you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments, the declaration allocates an array with 10 contiguous `*` character bytes in memory.